# Mongoose options for .find

Tags: mongoose, find

Trying to return the last 10 objects from Mongoose. Cannot figure out the find method. Any suggestions? {limit:10} is not working.

```js
router.get('/tweets', function(req, res, next){
  Tweet.find({}, ['createdAt'], {limit:10}, function(err,objects) { res.json(objects)});
  
});
```

Comment: Do you intend to get the lastest `10` records based on their `createdAt` date values? If that is the case, then, you need to add a `sort` by `createdAt` field in descending order to the method chain.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the method `limit` on find.

```
router.get('/tweets', function(req, res, next){
        Tweet.find({})
            .sort({'createdAt': -1})
            .limit(10)
            .exec(function(err,objects) { 
                res.json(objects)
            });
    });
```